# Make a textbox binded to a Double accepting dot in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, binding, textbox, double

I have a textbox in a VB.Net form binded to a Double.
The problem is that on binding validation it changes numbers like "11.7" to "117" because the Double conversion doesn't accept the dot.

How can I solve this problem without changing the dot to a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the set the proper [culture info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo) so that the framework can know the correct decimal separator.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
```

Add the following code in the contructor (Sub New) of your start up form.

```
Dim ci As New CultureInfo("it-IT")

ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci
```

Here's a list of culture codes where you can find yours:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx

**Edit**

Another way is to subscribe to the [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the binding.

```
Dim b As New Binding("Text", TheDataSource, "TheDoubleField")

AddHandler b.Parse, Sub(s As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs) e.Value = CStr(e.Value).Replace(".", ",")

Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(b)
```

Comment: Actually this way it accepts me the dot, but I need to know what other implications are involved. If I use my culture code it accepts only commas, but if I keep using en-US I guess I may encounter few problems. What about dates? Will this culture change other behaviours?

Comment: @DkSw Always use the `CulturInfo` corresponding to your region. I've provided an alternative solution. Please see my edit.

Comment: I set a copy of the Globalization and changed the DecimalSeparator this way: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("it-IT") Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "." and everything seems working. Is it a proper solution? Did I miss anything that can lead the application to return any error?

Comment: That should be sufficient. Just be aware that the `.net framework` uses the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` as a default (if no other is supplied). So now if you do `1.2#.ToString()` it will return `1.2` and not `1,2`.

Comment: I don't see any problem in that (for now xD). Thanks alot for the help! If you edit your post with the solution we came up with, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DkSw No problem, glad to help! I've edited the answer. FYI, i'm Norwegian and we also use `,` as decimal separator. So I know your struggle:p